# c++ : How to find the minimum library to include

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, header-files

My question is "when we come across a new function, how can we figure out what is the minimum header file/library to include?

In other words, is there a systematic way to figure out the required header/library for a certain function?

To clarify:

I googled and found `ofstream` to be handy for output I/O. I needed to include `<fstream>` to be able to use `ofstream`. how can I determine these two libraries and how to figure out the minimum required one? (well in this case, I googled again! or obviously I could search the filesystem for any file `.h` or `.so`or `.cpp` or ... that define this function )

Comment: `<ofstream>` doesn't exist as a header, `ofstream` is declared inside `fstream`. You need to read the documentation to figure that out.

Comment: Correct! [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) says `std::ofstream::ofstream` which means ofstream is an object in fstream that ofstream is its constructor

Comment: std is the namespace, ofstream the class inside the namespace and the last part you linked is the constructor of the class

Comment: Totally true, I edited my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation is the preferred way.
Searching the filesystems for the function name way too often leads astray - there are many headers that rely on code in a file that includes it in turn.

The [cppreference site](http://en.cppreference.com/) is a pretty good resource on the standard.

For platform specifics:
If you're on Windows, MSDN tells you exactly which header and library to include.
Linux and Unixes have their man pages.
OS X has the XCode documentation and man pages.

Answer (score 2):

Well you have answered your own question. Either google it or check the API documentation, they should mention what is to be included. For example "man strcpy" tells me that I need to include #include <string.h>.

Additionally,  you can also try to understand the relationship among the APIs. For example, [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/) provides ofstream and ifstream, so including fstream will help in that case.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. But I do not even fully understand cppreference, like  [here](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=ofstream)  I search for ofstream, it redirects me to `std::basic_ofstream` and says `Defined in header <fstream>` so I will never understand that including `ofstream` is enough. Even in `Input/output library` it does not show the relation between these two APIs.

Comment: @sali It is because `std::ofstream` is a typedef of a `std::basic_ofstream`, like `std::string` is a typedef of `std::basic_string`.

Comment: humm, that's what cppreference mean by `Two specializations for common character types are also defined`

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to standard C or C++, I usually use [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) to find which header file is related with what I want to use.

If it is Unix-related, then the [man pages](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/) are my friend.